# How to display magento contact page breadcrumbs?

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

I am new to magento. The contact page breadcrumb is not displaying. I can create a breadcrumb in magento contact page, but the breadcrumb is displaying on all pages.

Comment: Do you have any code to show that would help us to help you?

Comment: Refer for magento 2 http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/11/add-breadcrumbs-on-contact-page-magento.html.

Answer (score 11):

Yes i fix it. In contacts.xml i add the code

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>
  <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
      <crumbName>home</crumbName>
      <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
    </action> 
    <action method="addCrumb">
      <crumbName>contacts</crumbName>
      <crumbInfo><label>Contact us</label><title>Contact us</title></crumbInfo>
    </action>
  </block>
</reference>
```